# Googled a lot but can't figure this out: MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection

Tags: mongodb

Anyone know how to fix this? The first time I create a submission everything works fine. But the second time I get a duplicate key error. Tried changing my schema and adding in a "unique" key but could not get this working. I want mongo to create a new document every time I create a submission. Not sure why I'm getting a duplicate key.

```
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.submissions index:
submissions.questionNumber_1 dup key: { submissions.questionNumber: null }
...
<large stack trace>
...
keyPattern: { 'submissions.questionNumber': 1 },
  keyValue: { 'submissions.questionNumber': null }
}
```

Here's my schema:

```
const SubmissionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userID: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please specify a userID"]
    },
    questionNumber: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please specify question number"]
    },
    userSubmittedCode: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Please submit some code"]
    },
    codeResults: {
        type: String
    }
})
```

Creation code:

```
const submission = await Submission.create({
        userID,
        questionNumber,
        userSubmittedCode: code,
        codeResults: results
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I manually deleted the indexed in my Submission schema. Seems to be working...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).